# css sed unterminated address regex

Tags: linux, sed

The following sed command works great most of the time except when I try it with the following script. I get the error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 3495: unterminated address regex
```

It points at the last character } but I can't figure out how to terminate the sed command. Usually its not a problem. Hep would be appreciated.

```
sed -i '/body *{/,/}/c \
body{\
    z-index:1;\
    margin:0;\
    background-image: url("http://www.calmchess.com/images/frgrnd1366.png");\
    background-repeat:repeat;\
    }\
    \
#header0{\
    position:relative; \
    width:1100px; \
    height:114px; \
    text-align:center; \
    font-size:16px; \
    color:000000; \
    background-size:1100px 114px; \
    background-image: url("http://www.calmchess.com/images/854x480/header854x480_114_0.png"); \
    background-repeat: no-repeat; \
    }\
     \
#fullcontentcontainer0{ \
    position:relative; \
    z-index:0; \
    text-align:center; \
    font-size:16px; \
    color:000000;  \
    width:1100px; \
    height:135%; \
      } \
 \
 #lrgcontentimgcontainer0{ \
   position:relative; \
   top:75px; \
   margin:0 auto 0 auto; \
   font-size:16px;  \
   color:000000;  \
   width:530px;  \
   height:575px;  \
   background-size:530px 575px; \
   background-image: url("http://www.calmchess.com/images/lrgcontent0.png"); \
   background-repeat: no-repeat; \
     } \
 \
 #nav0{ \
     width:1100px; \
     height:60px; \
     position:absolute; \
     color:000000; \
     z-index:6; \
     font-size:16px; \
     border-top:1px solid 000000; \
     border-bottom:1px solid 000000; \
     background-image:url("http://www.calmchess.com/images/mediumformbak0.png");\
     background-repeat: no-repeat; \
     } \
 \
 .btncon0{ \
     position:relative; \
     width:205px; \
     height:60px; \
     margin:0 auto 0 auto; \
     } \
 \
#footer0{ \
    position:absolute; \
    top:100%; \
    width:100%; \
    height:180px; \
    font-size:16px; \
    border-top:1px solid 000000; \
    background-image: url("http://www.calmchess.com/images/mediumformbak0.png"); \
    background-repeat: no-repeat; \
    } \
    \
 .foliotop0{ \
     position:absolute; \
     width:100px; \
     height:35px;  \
     top:5px; \
     left:0px; \
     font-size:16px; \
     z-index:2; \
     background-size:100px 35px; \
     background-image: url("http://www.calmchess.com/images/port0.png"); \
     background-repeat: no-repeat; \
       } \
\
.foliobottom0{ \
    position:absolute; \
    width:100px; \
    height:35px;  \
    top:5px; \
    left:0px; \
    font-size:16px; \
    z-index:1; \
    background-size:100px 35px; \
    background-image: url("http://www.calmchess.com/images/buttonbottom0.png"); \
    background-repeat: no-repeat; \
    } \
\
.contacttop0{ \
    position:absolute; \
    width:100px; \
    height:35px; \
    top:5px; \
    left:105px; \
    font-size:16px; \
    z-index:2; background-size:100px 35px; \
    background-image: url("http://www.calmchess.com/images/contact0.png"); \
    background-repeat: no-repeat; \
    } \
\
.contactbottom0{ \
    position:absolute; \
    width:100px; \
    height:35px;  \
    top:5px; \
    left:105px; \
    font-size:16px; \
    z-index:1; \
    background-size:100px 35px; \
    background-image: url("http://www.calmchess.com/images/buttonbottom0.png"); \
    background-repeat: no-repeat; \
    } \
\
#paypal0{ \
    position:absolute; \
    left:460px; \
    top:840px; \
    font-size:21pt;\
    } \ 
\
#paypal0 input{ \
    width:300px; \
    height:150px; \
      } \
\
#para0{ \
    font-size:21pt; \
    position:absolute; \
    width:500px; \
    left:15px; \
    top:10px; \
    text-align:left; \
    } \
\
#para1{ \
    font-size:21pt; \
    position:absolute; \
    width:500px; \
    left:15px; \
    top:110px; \
    text-align:left; \
      } \
\
#para2{ \
    font-size:21pt; \
    position:absolute; \
    width:500px; \
    left:15px; \
    top:350px; \
    text-align:left; \
    } \
    \
#para3{ \
    font-size:21pt; \
    position:absolute; \
    width:500px; \
    left:15px; \
    top:445px; \
    text-align:left; \
    } \
    \
.businesscard0{ \
    width:640px; \
    height:480px; \
    margin:0 auto 0 auto; \
    font-size:16px; \
      }' $file0
```

Comment: Don't you want `r` with an unescaped file instead of this escaping monster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a backslash to mark a line break, no trailing spaces are allowed.

```
cat -n file_with_sed_code | grep '\\ \+$'
```

Comment: I don't have any trailing space yet I still get the error.

Comment: The code in your question contains one trailing space and if I remove it, I don't get the error anymore and sed's returncode is 0.

Comment: where do you remove the trailing space from? The end ?

Comment: Line 131. See: `cat -n file_with_sed_code | grep '\\ \+$'`

Comment: Thanks for your time I'll use the cat script in the future.

Comment: I'm glad I could help you.